# Nginx with GZIP not compressing Django responses even when it is enabled

Tags: django, nginx, gzip

I have a Django project that runs via Nginx web server. I've enabled gzip settings on `nginx.conf` like this:

```
gzip on;
    
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_min_length 256;
```

Now I have nginx upstream like this:

```
upstream example {
    keepalive 500;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80
    server_name example.com
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://ikhlas;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

In Django, I have a method that returns **JSON with 16MB of size** when I enabled gzip it returned to me **same JSON with 16MB of size** while having `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header.

Why it is not compressing Django responses even if gzip is enabled and returns Content-Encoding header?

Comment: did you find out the solution?